# ViewPagerFragments args (System.out.println() and TextView act differently)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have created a Fragements inside ViewPager and below is my part-code:
(System.out.println(mNum) not printing actual values but TextView is. For example when sliding fragments from left to right, in second fragment, it prints 1 but when sliding right to left it prints 2, although TextView display it properly in both cases. 
From Android.Developers http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
            viewPager=(ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            System.out.println(mNum);
            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using viewPager:
Lets say you are in screen 1, screen 2 is also loaded into memory by the viewPager but its not visible. Since screen 2 fragment is instantiated , you get the output of screen 2 in 'System.out.println(mNum);'.

For more info [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))